# Is there a way to extract everyone at once?

Tags: xcom-2

I was doing an escort mission and got all of my troops plus the VIP into the extraction zone. Then I was sad to find that I had to click, one by one, to extract them individually, watching the animation play each time.

Is there any way to do a mass extraction?

Answer (score 15):

There is now a mod to add this feature: [Evac all](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=618669868).

However, note that even without it, you don't have to *"watch the animation play each time"* - you can hit tab after extracting a unit to immediately move onto the next one.

Comment: Also, if you evac the next unit while the other animation is stil running, it will finish the previous unit's evac instantly and start evacing yours. So I run all my guys up to the zone, and then just spam the evac (usually the 3 key) and tab keys. If you spam it, you only have to _watch_ the last unit's evac.